# Disable Win+1-9 Hotkeys

Tags: windows, desktop, hotkeys

Just downloaded Dexpot (virtual desktop application), and would like to assign the desktop switch hotkeys to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, but these are already being used the by the system.

Is there an easy way to disable only these particular hotkeys in order to free them up?

Comment: You should try [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Without more detail I don't really know how the script should look like, but it seems to me that AHK can do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

AutoHotKey would probably be the easiest path here. Set the desktop hotkeys to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd>, then for each number key, the script would look like this:

```
#1::Send !1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't tell how to _disable_ the system-wide hotkeys. It mentions to reassign them some other value but also doesn't tell how.